# Setting the items after creating ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

In my app, I am showing a list of items downloaded from internet (of type `pItem`). I am using a custom ArrayAdapter that extends `ArrayAdapter<pItem>` which is basically like this:

```
public class PArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<pItem> {

private List<pItem> pList = new ArrayList<pItem>();

public PArrayAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.p_row);
    this.context = context;
}


public void SetList(List<PItem> pl){
    pList = pl;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        rowView = vi.inflate(R.layout.p_row, null);
    }

    // ...

    return rowView;
}

}
```

Now, normally when creating a custom ArrayAdapter, the list of items is set in the constructor. But in my case, as I dynamically fetch the items in an `AsyncTask` (the list is changing constantly), I separated the setting of the items with the creation of the adapter.

In my main activity, this is what I do: (only the main part of the code)

```
public class MainPageActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
OnScrollListener {

// List of items
private List<pItem> pList = new ArrayList<pItem>();

// Adapter
private arrayAdapter pAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

    //...

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.p_list);

    adpater = new PArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    new ASTask().execute("");
}

private class ASTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Add the downloaded items to list
        pList.addAll(Downloader.GetItems());

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("Main", String.valueOf(pList.size())); // Shows the right number

        // Show Items
        pAdapter.setList(pList);
        listView.setAdapter(pAdapter);

        Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        Runnable rn = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        mHandler.post(rn);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}

}


}
```

Here is the problem: When I run it, **nothing is shown in the listView**. It doesn't give any errors.

But if I set the list in the constructor of `PArrayAdapter`, everything works fine and I see the items.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your data comes based onDemand ?  I means data comes in slots or 10 or 20 when scroll.

Comment: @MehulRanpara, It comes by a constant number (5) when calling `GetItems()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found what was my problem. It was actually a rookie mistake:

Instead of assigning the input list to the list inside adapter:

```
pList = pl;
```

I should have add all the items like this:

```
pList.addAll(pl);
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
at the end of onPostExecute() method.

Try like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("Main", String.valueOf(pList.size())); // Shows the right number

        // Show Items
        pAdapter.setList(pList);
        listView.setAdapter(pAdapter);
        pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();       
    }
```

Comment: I have it. You mean move it to the end and outside of the runnable?

Comment: Try this. Remove pAdapter.setList(pList); from onPostExecute() and move it to onCreate();

Answer (score 0):

in onPostExecute

remove this code

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    Runnable rn = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    mHandler.post(rn);
```

add this line only

```
pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.